# MySQL: Attendance Monitoring App Trouble

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, timeout, monitoring

How do I update a specific field without replacing all the other fields with the  same row field.

For example: I want to change this.(figure 1)

```
    date_id    employee_id    time_in     time_out
      1            3           1:00P        2:00P
      2            2           3:20P        3:49P
      3            2           3:20P        3:49P
```

To (figure 2)

```
    date_id    employee_id    time_in     time_out
      1            3           1:00P        2:00P
      2            2           3:20P        3:49P
      3            2         > 5:10P        6:29P <
```

But what happen is, it goes back to figure 1 again.
Over writing all fields with the same value as employee_id.
Any other ways of doing this?

The query I used:

> UPDATE 'attendance' SET time_out = ? WHERE employee_id = ?

Yes I'm making simple Time In and Time Out application(Java).

[SOLVED My problem] but not the question, there is no way to update it using 'employee_id'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the primary key to identify the exact row, If you do not have a primary key
try this way:

```
UPDATE 'attendance' SET time_out = ? WHERE employee_id = ? AND date_id=?
```

Comment: Okay thanks this maybe helpful, let me get back at you after I try code this in Java.
I'm really new to this database logic thing.

Comment: In this it is a very simple logic, you just have to think only about the unique data for the specific row.

Comment: But I need to use only the employee_id.
Not gonna touch the date_id(which is unique).

Still having a problem coding your answer though.

Comment: There is no way to update your row without touching the `date_id`.

Comment: So what I wanted was not possible I see, thanks for the replying though.

What I wanted was to update time_out using only the employee_id(which has many duplicates and not unique).

So I changed my program a bit so I guess its okay now.

Comment: @PaulØmega I’m happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

As chalitha lawanga said, but a little simpler:

```
UPDATE 'attendance' SET time_out = ? WHERE date_id = ?
```

If `date_id` is a PK, then `employee_id` is not needed in your statement.

Comment: Actually I need this employee_id to identify who timed in.

Comment: @PaulØmega But it's not needed. If `date_id` is a PK, then `employer_id` is redundant.

Comment: I need the employee ID to use it for reports later on.

Comment: You do not need to delete the `employee_id` column from your table. @romanoza said only to use the `date_id` row when updating a specific row.

Comment: @PaulØmega That's right. You should remove `employee_id` from the `UPDATE` statement only, not from the table.

Comment: So what I wanted was not possible I see, thanks for the replying though.

What I wanted was to update time_out using only the employee_id(which has many duplicates and not unique).

So I changed my program a bit so I guess its okay now.